# Printing phonegap page in iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, printing

I am currently having issue where I have to print / get PDF file from a page where I am currently, in my Phonegap application. Page contains images and text. My application works on android and iOS. I am using cordova-plugin-printer to get "webpage" to native(?) printing software to be able to print / get PDF file and this works perfectly with android, but it's not working in iOS. So what plugin / code / workaround, I should use to do this same thing with iOS what I am doing with android now.

Below is the code I am using and it works fine with android, but in iOS it's not even going to first alert.

```
function printPage(){
    cordova.plugins.printer.isAvailable(function (isAvailable) {
        alert(isAvailable ? 'Service is available' : 'Service NOT available');

        var page = document.getElementById('Content');

        cordova.plugins.printer.print(page, 'Document.html', function () {
            alert('printing finished or canceled');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: are you testing in iOS device or simulator? iOS version?

Comment: @Gandhi I am using iOS device and even close iPad. Not really sure about the version 'cause don't have the device right now, but if I recall it's iOS 7 or 8, but more likely iOS 8.

Comment: Hello VSmoL, i am facing same problem if you get ant solution then please let me know.